# $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ Countably Infinite

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I want to do this using an infinite grid as it seems easiest to me but I am open to other suggestions as well to improve my understanding.

My attempt: $$\begin{array}{c | c | c | c | c}
(0,0) & (1,0) & (-1,0) & (2,0) & (-2,0).....\\ \hline (0,1) & (1,1) & (-1,1) & (2,1) & (-2,1).....\\ \hline (0,2) & (1,2) & (-1,2) & (2,2) & (-2,2)..... \\ \hline (0,3) & (1,3) & (-1,3) & (2,3) & (-2,3).....
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c | c | c | c | c}
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15.....\\ \hline 2 & 5 & 9 & 14 & 20.....\\ \hline 4 & 8 & 13 & 19 & 26..... \\ \hline 7 & 12 & 18 & 25 & 33.....
\end{array}$$

The columns also extend down by an infinite amount. I then tried to create a bijection from $\Bbb N$ $->$ $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ by starting from the top left at $(0,0)$, and then preceding up each diagonal from bottom left to top right. So $1$ maps to $(0,0)$, $2$ maps to $(0,1)$, $3$ maps to $(1,0)$ and so on. This creates a bijection $f$: $\Bbb N$ $->$ $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ in which each natural number maps to the pair ($a,b)$ in the grid above. I then explained why this is both injective and surjective to give a bijection.

Comment: It is important to enumerate the pairs in such a way that every pair will occur after a finite amount of time. This is here easy : Write down the pairs with maximum absolute value $0$ , then $1$ , then $2$ and so on. This is a successful enumeration and shows that the given set is countable.

Comment: @Peter So $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$....?

Comment: Probably the easiest method to convince yourself, is to "draw" it. You can scetch $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ as points in the plane. Now find a method of connecting the dots without missing one.

Comment: The first entries are correct , but $(-1,-1)$ does not belong to the set.

Comment: @Cornman My bad, $0$ isn't a natural number. I tried and I got $(1,1),(-1,1),(-2,1),(-2,2),(-1,2),(0,2),(1,2)(2,2),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(2,3),(1,3),(0,3),(-1,3),(-2,3),(-3,3),(-3,2),(-3,1),(-4,1),(-4,2)$....   Does that mean I can draw the cartesian plane showing those points and draw another one with the natural numbers in that order and explain why there exists a bijection ?

Comment: @Peter Say if I wanted to prove that the rational numbers were infinite. Could I draw two grids, one with the positive rationals and another with the negative rationals and that would show they are countably infinite due to a bijection with the natural numbers. Then because the union of countable sets is countable, the union of the positive rationals, negative rationals, and $0$ is countable, so the entire set of rationals is countable ? I tried to do it with an infinite grid in one go but I got stuck. I'm not sure on this method because there will be repeats in the grid.

Comment: 1. You can consider $0$ to be a natural number as long as you clarify it. There is no convention about this. 2. To enumerate the rational numbers, you again write down all fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ with max(|a|,|b|)=1 , max(|a|,|b|)=2 , max(|a|,|b|)=3 and so on. If a value duplicates, just omit this fraction and continue.

Comment: This diagonal method works. Note that when you use the bijection from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by the sequence $0,1,-1,2,-2,...$ you're mapping the negatives and positives to even and odd numbers. This technique generalizes either by iterating the positive/negative mapping to build up bijections or by using remainders modulo $n$ to partition the integers into a finite union of countable sets.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin:  yes, drawing two grids is fine.  You can then just say you have shown that each grid is countable previously (I suppose you have) and then the union of two countable sets is countable.  It is quite common to make a chain of equivalences for a problem like this.  You don't have to demonstrate an end-to-end bijection, just that there is one for each step along the way.

Comment: @RossMillikan My issue is with the duplicate / repeated fractions that are unsimplified like for $\frac{2}{4}$. I know I can miss them out but then I'm skipping natural numbers in my grid.

Comment: You can also show injections both ways.  The naturals inject into the fractions using just the fractions with denominator $1$.  The rationals inject into the naturals using the grid and ignoring the ones that are reducible.

Comment: @Peter check my answer below please

Answer (score 3):

Okay so taking the ideas together I have this for proving $\Bbb Q$ is countably infinite.

First, let's look at $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ and prove this is countably infinite. We can write the elements of $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ on an infinite grid as shown below.

[image]

The right hand side shows how the elements of this grid may be labelled with elements of $\Bbb N$, by taking $max(|a|,b)$ where $a \in \Bbb Z$ and $b \in \Bbb N$. This creates a bijection from  $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$, namely the function $f$ : $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ -> $\Bbb N$, in which each $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$ in the right hand grid maps to the pair $(a, b)$ in the
corresponding position in the left hand grid (so, for instance, $f(5) = (-2, 2)$ and $f(8) = (1, 2))$. Indeed, $f$ is well-defined since every natural number appears once in the right hand grid and so is mapped to exactly
one pair in the left-hand grid; $f$ is injective and surjective since each pair appears precisely once in the left-hand grid so is mapped to by exactly one element of $\Bbb N$. The existence of this bijection proves that
$\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ is countably infinite.

Now, I want to prove there exists a surjection $g$: $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$ -> $\Bbb Q$, defined for $m$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z$ and $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, by $(m,n) -> \frac{m}{n}$. This is clearly a surjective function because every rational number has at least one preimage in $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N$. However, it isn't injective because some pairs $(m,n)$ map to the same rational number, such as $g((1,2)) = g((2,4)) = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$. So surjective.

Then $|\Bbb Q$| $\leq$ $|\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $\Bbb N|$ $=$ $\Bbb N$. Since $\Bbb N$ $\subseteq$ $\Bbb Q$ it follows from the CSB theorem that $|\Bbb N|$ $\leq$ $|\Bbb Q|$, so $|\Bbb N|$ $=$ $|\Bbb Q|$ and hence the $\Bbb Q$ is countably infinite. $\square$

Comment: @mathlander You're saying it looks okay then ? Cheers for the edit : )

Comment: It looks much better this way.

Comment: @mathlander Thanks. I think my proof is pretty good but I am sure it would have been easier just using an infinite grid of rationals on its own. Could anyone tell me how to do it / post a link for it ? thanks.

Comment: @mathlander I made some mistakes which I edited just now. My question is - is the first paragraph really required for this proof ? I don't see why I need to prove that the cartesian product of integers and naturals is countably infinite. Couldn't I just skip straight to showing there exits a surjection from the integers crossed with the naturals to the rationals ?

Answer (score 2):

You can define bijections in terms of other bijections.

To define the bijection: $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$

$1 \to (1,1)$
$2\to (1,2); 3\to (2,1)$
$4\to (1,3); 5\to (2,2); 6\to (3,1)$ etc.

we not if the term $(a,b)$ is in the $k$th diagonal then $a+b=k+1$.  To get to the $k$th diagonal we had to go through $k-1$ diagonals with increasing numbers of terms.  So be fore we got to $f(n) = (a,b)$ where $a+b = k+1$ we had to got through a diagonals with $1,2,3,...,k-1$ terms.  That is $\sum_{j=1}^{a+b-1} j$ terms.  Then thes is the $a$th term so $(a,b) = f(a+ \sum_{j=1}^{a+b-1})$ or

$f^{-1}(a,b) = a+\sum_{j=1}^{a+b-1} j$.

That is enough to define $f: \mathbb N\to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.  Note: You *DON'T* need to actually solve and write a formula for a bijection to know that it exists.

We can show that $f^{-1}(a,b) = a+\sum_{j=1}^{a+b-1}j$ is a bijection because all for all natural $n$ there is a unique value of $k$ so that $1+2+ .... + k \le n < 1+2+.... + k + (k+1)$ so let $a = n-k$ and let $b=k+1-a$ so $f^{-1}(a,b)=n$ so $f^{-1}$ is surjective.  And if $f^{-1}(a,b) = f^{-1}(\alpha, \beta) = n$ we must have that $a+b-1= k =\alpha + \beta -1$ and that $a=n-k=\alpha$ and $b=k+1-a=k+1-\alpha = \beta$ so $(\alpha, \beta)=(a,b)$ so $f^{-1}$ is injective.

And so $f^{-1}$ is a bijections from $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ so $f:\mathbb N \to  \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is a bijection.

Then we know that $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ via $g(n) = \frac {n+1}2$ if $n$ is odd (maps the odd numbers to positive integers) and $g(n) =-(\frac n2 -1)$ if $n$ is even (maps the even numbers to non-positive integers) is a bijections.

We know this is surjective.  If $z\in \mathbb Z$ and $z > 0$ then $2z- 1\in \mathbb N$ and is odd so $g(2z-1) = \frac{(2z-1)+1}2 = z$.  ANd if $z \le 0$ then $-z\ge 0$ and $-z + 1\in \mathbb N$ and $2(-z+1)$ is even so $f(2(-z+1))= -(\frac {2(-z+1)}2-1)=-((-z+1)-1)=-(-z)=z$.  So $g$ is surjective.

And if $g(n)=g(m)=z$ then either $z>0$ and therefore $n,m$ are both odd and $\frac{n+1}2 = \frac {m+1}2$ so $m =n$ or $z\le 0$ and $n,m$ are both even so $-(\frac n2 -1)=-(\frac m2-1)$ and $m =n$.  So $f$ is surjective.

So combining we can go from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by considering

For $(a,b)$ $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $b \in \mathbb N$ we can define $h^{-1}(a,b) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}a, b)$.  $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb N$ so $(g^{-1}(a),b) \in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ and so $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(a),b)\in \mathbb N$.  And we know $h^{-1}: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is a bijection because it is a composition of bijections.

So $h:\mathbb N\to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N$ is a bijection.

Again.  We *don't* need a formula or an equation to know that something is a bijection.

But if you want.

To find $h(n)$.  Find the unique $k$ so that $1+2+3+.... + k \le n < 1+2+3 +..... +k + (k+1)$.

Let $a = n-k$ and let $b = k+1-a$.  Now let $c = \frac {a+1}2$ if $a$ is odd or $c =-(\frac a2 -1)$ if $a$ is even.

$h(n) = (c,a)$.